# Inject annotation based Bean into an xml based bean

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-ioc

My persistence configuration Class looks like bellow :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    // code here

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        System.out.println("------------------------datasource----------------------");
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }


}
```

And i have an xml configuration class :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd ">

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
                            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
     <authentication-provider>

        <user-service>
            <user name="username" password="password" authorities="USER_ROLE" />
        </user-service>


        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                               users-by-username-query="query here"
                               authorities-by-username-query="query here" />

    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
<!-- code here -->
```

So i want to inject the bean called "*dataSource*" annotated with **@Bean** (in the persistence config class) , in `<jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" ... >` , how can I do it ?

Comment: It depends on how you boostrap spring. If you manage to load both the `@Configuration` class and the xml file it will work. If it does not, show how you do.

Comment: @SergeBallesta ,I Think it should be loaded both the @Configuration class and xml file , because I configure it in my xml file : 

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.rsone.*" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/> `

Comment: The hard part when beginning with spring is to correctly load the application contextes. If you do not say it, I won't be able to help. How are you bootstrapping Spring ? From web.xml, from a `WebApplicationInitializer` ?

Comment: what is `xml bean spring` supposed to mean?

Comment: @SergeBallesta from web.xml

Comment: @specializt it mean to inject a bean using xml method

Comment: that ... doesnt make any sense whatsoever. There is no such think like a "xml method" - there are XML **bean declarations**, though - and these are used to instantiate and inject beans during **runtime**

Comment: @specializt I meant the xml way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by changing the loading order of my config files so that Spring load the config file that contains :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.rsone.*" />
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

before my webSecurityConfig.xml ( the above config file )

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            WEB-INF/mvc-servlet.xml
            classpath:webSecurityConfig.xml
        </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Glad you solved you problem, but acknowledge it was hard to guess for us :-)

Comment: Tanks for your help guys ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<bean class="PersistenceConfig.class"/>
```

in your xml config

tip: make sure you have this post processor

```
<bean class="org.springframework.config.java.process.ConfigurationPostProcessor"/>
```

Comment: it give me `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined `

Comment: @AbelRoussi make sure you have this post processor

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are loading xml configuration before the PersistenceConfig class which is creating "dataSource" bean. Load the class first and then your xml configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd ">
  <context:component-scan base-package="your_package.PersistenceConfig" /> 
    <context:annotation-config /><mvc:annotation-driven/> 
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
                            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
     <authentication-provider>

        <user-service>
            <user name="username" password="password" authorities="USER_ROLE" />
        </user-service>


        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                               users-by-username-query="query here"
                               authorities-by-username-query="query here" />

    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
<!-- code here -->
```